# Determining the order of shapes in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that contains text boxes (about 30 of them) that are moved around. I need to know the order of the boxes.

In Word 2016 `Activedocument.Shapes` returns the shapes in the order they appear in the document, however that is not the case for Word 2007 (they are in the order they were added). Since I want it to work in Office 2007 I'm looking for a workaround.

I use `box.wrapformat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapInline` to convert the boxes to act like inline shapes since `.ConvertToInlineShape` isn't available in office 2007 but this doesn't actually convert them to inline shapes.

Edit: I just noticed neither does `.ConvertToInlineShape`. The box doesn't appear in the `InlineShapes` collection but if I select it the selection type is `wdSelectionInlineShape`.

Is there a way to force Word to reassign the shapes in the shapes collection or is there another way to get references to the shapes in the correct order?

I am thinking about looping through the characters of the document (selecting each and checking the type) but this seems rather slow.

Comment: In *all* versions of Word `Shape` objects are in the order of their *anchors* in the document, not in the order they seem to be on a page (whatever criterium you may use). If what you consider "in order" is the order of indexing you're getting in 2016 VBA, then it's really just coincidence. About the only thing you can do is loop the collection and check whatever positional criteria you determine as "the order", possibly assigning the Shapes to an Array or Collection, then access them again from the array or collection to "read" them in order. Why is that important?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The anchor of an inline shape should be the same position as the box appears in the document right? So the order the boxes appear in the document should be the same as the order of the anchors. 
I'm creating an exam and the questions should be shuffled automatically to create different versions. To create the solutions and renumber the questions I need to know which question is where. I use textboxes because they behave much nicer than tables for my purposes (no splitting over pages, no concatenating when placed to close to another)

Comment: InlineShapes don't have an anchor: they *are* in the position (in the text flow) where they appear. The Anchor of a *Shape* can be anywhere on the page (next to the beginning of any paragraph). My inclination for your requirement would be Content Controls: the entire information inside a Content Control and shuffle the content controls.

Comment: The weird thing is that the boxes are not in the inlineshapes collection, even if I convert them using `ConvertToinlIneShape`. The `Anchor` property still works too.

I will look into Content Controls, thank you.

Comment: Mmm, yes, "Drawing objects" cannot be "InlineShapes", they can only be formatted to lay out "in-line". It's simply how MS designed them...